# Why does my custom UITableViewCell remain selected after calling deselectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` (implementation below) that is not getting deselected when after popping a child view controller. I am not using a `UITableViewController`. I am using a `UIViewController` whose view contains the tableView.

Here's the relevant viewWillAppear that attempts to deselect the selected cell:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSIndexPath *selection = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (selection) {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selection animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I've confirmed that `self.tableView` is not nil when the code above is called.

Custom `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
@implementation DSCaseCell

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setStatus:(NSString *)status
{
    _status = status;
    self.statusLabelView.backgroundColor = [DSStyles colorForCaseStatus:self.status];
    self.statusLabel.text = [self.status capitalizedString];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    if ([self.status isEqualToString:DSInteractionClassFacebookComment]) {
        self.iconView.image = [UIImage iconForInteractionClass:self.status];
    } else {
        self.iconView.image = [UIImage iconForInteractionClass:self.messageClass];
    }

    self.statusLabel.font = [DSStyles preferredFontForTextStyle:DSFontTextStyleCaption2];
    self.statusLabelView.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    self.statusLabelView.backgroundColor = [DSStyles colorForCaseStatus:self.status];
    self.statusLabel.text = [self.status capitalizedString];
    self.statusLabel.textColor = [DSStyles invertedTextColor];
    self.statusLabel.highlightedTextColor = [DSStyles invertedTextColor];

    self.fromLabel.font = [DSStyles preferredFontForTextStyle:DSFontTextStyleLightCaption1];
    self.timeLabel.font = [DSStyles preferredFontForTextStyle:DSFontTextStyleLightCaption1];


    self.descriptionLabel.font = [DSStyles preferredFontForTextStyle:DSFontTextStyleLightCaption1];
    [super layoutSubviews];
}

@end
```

Comment: Is indexPathForSelectedRow returning non-nil in viewWillAppear?

Comment: Yes, it is non-nil. I confirmed that the if clause is evaluating to true and that deselectRowForIndexPath:animated is getting called.

Comment: I wonder if viewWillAppear is too early in the view pipeline. Can you try viewDidAppear and see if that works?

Comment: Just tried that--still no luck.

Comment: I even tried putting this in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` but it didn't work: `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was being caused by the following code in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Changing it to this fixed the issue:

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Not sure what I was drinking with that first attempt.